# Cannot sent to gmail account using mail() function

Tags: php, sendmail

Hi can anyone help why can't I send email to a gmail account.I have been doing change password module and to confirm the password i will send the confirmation link to my clients email account.Many have contact me that they have not receive any emails. Here's my code:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1  \r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: ".$from;
mail($sendmail_recipient_email, $sendmail_subject, $sendmail_message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for one, your `$headers` are just going to be

```
"From: ".$from;
```

because you're not using a concatenation operator. Should be:

```
$headers .= "From: ".$from;
```

note the `.=`

### EDIT

The OP corrected the code in the question, so I'll modify my answer. There are LOTS of reasons that gmail might be rejecting your emails, but a good first step would be to remove the `\r` line-break modifiers. `\n` should suffice, and [lots of folks](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/php-mail-and-gmail) seem to have solved this exact issue (specific rejection by Gmail) by only using new-line breaks and excluding return breaks.